# POSTed JSON to Google Apps Script, need to extract value and place in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am posting a JSON to Google Apps Script and want to display a specific value from that JSON in Google Sheets.

I use the following code to get the data into my sheet [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127023/how-do-i-create-a-doposte-function-in-apps-script-project-to-capture-http-post)

```
function doPost(e) {
    Logger.log("I was called")
    if (typeof e !== 'undefined')
        Logger.log(e.parameter);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID here")
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e))
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e))
}
```

My sheet now displays:

```
{
   "parameter":{

   },
   "contextPath":"",
   "contentLength":20,
   "queryString":"",
   "parameters":{

   },
   "postData":{
      "type":"application/json",
      "length":20,
      "contents":"{\"myValue\":13}",
      "name":"postData"
   }
}
```

I only want it to display the value for myValue - which is the number 13 in this example.

I've tried a number of things suggested on these forums, I figured I was getting there with the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956354/how-to-access-body-of-post-request-in-app-script-using-dopostrequest), and changed the code to:

```
function doPost(e) {
    Logger.log("I was called")
    if (typeof e !== 'undefined')
        Logger.log(e.parameter);
    var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString(); //added line
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString); // added line
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID here")
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(JSON.stringify(jsonData.myValue)) //changed "e" to jsonData.myValue
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(jsonData.myValue)) //changed "e" to jsonData.myValue
}
```

This didn't work.

As a simple marketer, I wrestled with this for 2 nights now and feel I am pretty much stuck. So any help would be kindly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
function doPost(request) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID here")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  // Now Parse the body of your post request in to a data object

  var data = JSON.parse (request.postData.contents)
  //Now put the data in the sheet
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(data['myValue'])
  // Note no need to stringify 
  // now do your other stuff
```

The body of the post request is available to you in `request .postData.contents`. [Here's the Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

You parse the content string into a JSON object and then access the fields you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it! 
When I try your code, I keep getting an error on line 6 - TypeError: Cannot read property "postData" from undefined - when trying to parse the postdata contents.

I changed "request" to "e" on line 6 since I guess this is a mixup from the two example posts I linked to. But both give the error.

Any idea what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: My code had a bug. I was cutting and pasting from another code. I have changed it - see if it works now. If it does not, if you post the last version of your code that causing the error, I should be able to help you get passed it. Good luck

Comment: The changed code works like a charm and solved my problem. Thank you for taking the time to figure this one out for me!