# `POST` request to script page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The function below is contained in the Apps Script `code.gs` file:

```
function doPost(e) {
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined')
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
}
```

If I make a request using `fetch` from the `background.js` of my Chrome extension and include the `id` parameter in the URL, I get the expected result.

```
const url = 'https://script.google.com/.../exec?id=123';

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => { console.log(data) }) // {"id":"123"}
```

Instead of writing `id` as a parameter in the URL, I would like to make the request using the `POST` method.

I tried to use the object below, but I don't know how to include the variable I want to send:

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: {}
}
```

Comment: have you tried `body: { id: 123 }` ? And then seems that the data would be available as `JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)` in your function (see this prior question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956354/how-to-access-body-of-post-request-in-app-script-using-dopostrequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to send the value of `id=123` with the request body instead of the query parameter.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
    const value = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); // This is the value from the request body.
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(value));
  }
}
```

#### Javascript side:

```js
const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";
const data = { id: 123 };
fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify(data) })
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then((res) => console.log(res));
```

- By this modification, you can see the value of `{"id":123}` in the console.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

To include the data you want to send in the request body and to make a POST request using the fetch function, you can do the following:

```
const data = {id: '123'};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => { console.log(data) })
```

This send a POST request to the URL with data in the request body. The server-side function (in this case, doPost) will receive the data in the e.parameter object.

I hope this helps you.